# js validate two forms

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, paypal

This is my first time posting, I am new to JavaScript and working on an order page with two PayPal forms on the same page. The code for both forms is the same, but one for adult version of a product and one for kids.

I have created a select drop-down that asks for client feedback, and made the drop-down required through a JavaScript validation script. The script works for the first product/form, but if the customer wants to buy the second product, but doesn't fill out the required field for the first form, they cannot validate/buy the product.

I have tried using two different scripts, but of course, the first form won't validate if it is left blank, even if the customer is only trying to buy the second product.

I think a solution might be to add an "else" or "while" argument to the script that says that if there is feedback for #1 **or** #2 it will validate, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
function validateForm() {
var x=document.forms["myPayPal"]["os1"].value
if (x==null || x=="") {
alert("Please tell us how you heard about our product");
return false;
}
}


<form name="myPayPal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="payPalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="1234567890123">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="OUR PRODUCT">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.99">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:add-to-cart.png:NonHostedGuest">
<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 4% 3% 1% 0">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="CHOOSE STYLE"><h2 style="float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 0 30px 0 0">CHOOSE <br>STYLE:</h2>
<div class="styled-select" style="margin:0;">
<select name="os0" class="select"><option value="White">White $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Green">Green $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Kid's Pink">Kid's Pink $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Kid's Aqua">Kid's Aqua $13.95 USD</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="White">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Blue">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Green">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="Yellow">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="Pink">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="Aqua">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<!--select !-->
<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 3% 1% 0; float:left; height:60px; clear:both; position:relative; left: 13.9%;">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="REFERRAL"><p style="float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 19px 30px 0 3px; font-weight:normal;">How did you hear about us?</p>
<div class="styled-select" style="margin:0;">
<select name="os1">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="Online">Online </option>
    <option value="Through a friend">Through a friend </option>
    <option value="Google">Google </option>
    <option value="My doctor">My doctor </option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<!--end select !-->
<input type="image" src="add-to-cart.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="" class="add-to-cart" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; left: 13.9%; margin: 1.5% 0px; float:left; clear: both;">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a piece of javascript to check if atleast os0 or os1 is selected or not.

```
    function validateForm() {
var y=document.forms["myPayPal"]["os0"].value
var x=document.forms["myPayPal"]["os1"].value

 if (x==null && y==null){
 alert("Please select one option product");
return false;
}


if (x==null || x=="") {
alert("Please tell us how you heard about our product");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I appreciate your help! I tried this script, but when I added it in, neither validation requirement was active, it went through without the alert when I had neither selection. This is the code I used: 'function validateForm() {
var x=document.forms["myPayPal"]["os1"].value
var x=document.forms["myPayPal"]["os2"].value

if (x==null && y==null){
alert("Please select one option product");
return false;
}if (x==null || x=="") {
alert("Please tell us how you heard about us");
return false;
}
}

'

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {


if( document.myPayPal.os0.value == "-2" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your OS0 !" );
     return false;
   }

if( document.myPayPal.os1.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your OS1 !" );
     return false;
   }
   return( true );

}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="myPayPal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="return(validateForm());" method="post" id="payPalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="1234567890123">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="OUR PRODUCT">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.99">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:add-to-cart.png:NonHostedGuest">

<!--select !-->
<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 4% 3% 1% 0">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="CHOOSE STYLE"><h2 style="float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 0 30px 0 0">CHOOSE <br>STYLE:</h2>
<div class="styled-select" style="margin:0;">
<select name="os0" class="select">
<option selected value="-2">[choose your os0]</option>
<option value="White">White $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Green">Green $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Kid's Pink">Kid's Pink $13.95 USD</option>
<option value="Kid's Aqua">Kid's Aqua $13.95 USD</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<!--end select !-->

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="White">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Blue">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Green">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="Yellow">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="Pink">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="Aqua">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="13.95">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<!--select !-->

<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 3% 1% 0; float:left; height:60px; clear:both; position:relative; left: 13.9%;">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="REFERRAL"><p style="float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 19px 30px 0 3px; font-weight:normal;">How did you hear about us?</p>
<div class="styled-select" style="margin:0;">
<select name="os1">
    <option selected value="-1">[choose your os1]</option>
    <option value="Online">Online </option>
    <option value="Through a friend">Through a friend </option>
    <option value="Google">Google </option>
    <option value="My doctor">My doctor </option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<!--end select !-->
<input type="submit"  value="submit" border="0" name="submit" alt="" class="add-to-cart" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; left: 13.9%; margin: 1.5% 0px; float:left; clear: both;">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! The following script worked such that one has to select one drop down in order to validate. The issue is that os1 and os2 are in separate forms in separate parts of the page, but both input fields are required, but only for their respective product. Does that make sense?  '<script>
function validateForm() {
    var os1 = document.forms["myPayPal"]["os1"].value;
    var os2 = document.forms["myPayPal"]["os2"].value;

    if ( (os1 == null || os1 == "") && (os2 == null || os2 == "")) {
        alert("Please tell us how you heard about us");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>'

Comment: Your logic is wobbling to me. Can you write a pseudo code for your logic?